# creating multiple infowindows in Bing Maps v7 and presenting data specific to pin

Tags: javascript, jquery, bing-maps

I'm currently trying to learn the Bing Maps API and currently trying to build a map with multiple pins that can be hovered to reveal a info window with that pins data. At the moment I'm experiencing a few problems. If anyone could help with the following points that would be great:

1. When I mouseleave a pin the info window doesn't get removed?
2. How can I use the data I retrieve in the addPin() to populate the
   required info window?
3. In createInfoBox() I want to hide any active info window when the
   map gets moved but this seems to get triggered even if the map isn't
   moved?
4. If there are any improvements i can make please let me know

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/vpepD/23/ and JS below

**JS**

```
var dealerMap = {        

        createInfoBox: function(infobox) {

            var instance = this,
                pushpin = infobox;

            // Now create infowindows
            var NewWindow = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(pushpin.getLocation(), {
                title: 'title',
                offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(-3, pushpin.getHeight() - 5),
                zIndex: 999,
                visible: true
            });

            //Display infowindow
            instance.displayInfoBox(NewWindow, pushpin);

            //Hide infowindow if map is moved - currently gets run without moving map
            //Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(dealerMap.myMap, 'viewchange', instance.hideInfoBox(NewWindow));

        },

        displayInfoBox: function(infobox, pin) {

            var instance = this;

            //Show updated infowindow
            dealerMap.myMap.entities.push(infobox);

            //Mouse out handler to remove window
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'mouseleave', function() {        
                instance.hideInfoBox(NewWindow);
            });
        },

        hideInfoBox: function(infobox) {

            var instance = this;

            console.log('this was called');
            dealerMap.myMap.entities.remove(infobox);

        },

        addPin: function() {

            var instance = this;

            //make $.ajax json call            
            var response = data.dummy;

            //on success make each pin with returned data
            for (var i = 0, len = response.length; i < len; i++) {    

                var responseItem = response[i],
                    pinLocation = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(responseItem.lat, responseItem.long);                       

                //Create new pin
                var NewPin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(pinLocation, {
                    icon: 'http://www.kylehouston.com/testing/sportscar_' + responseItem.id +'.png',
                    width: 32,
                    height: 37
                });    

                //Push new pin onto map
                this.myMap.entities.push(NewPin);          

                //Event handlers to show and hide requested infowindow information
                Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(NewPin, 'mouseover', function(e) {
                    console.log(this);
                    dealerMap.createInfoBox(e.target);
                });
            }                      
        },

        init: function() {

            var instance = this;

            var mapOptions = {
                credentials: "AvGoKWSuMorGQb5h4UyyatCBGmGzSZe7-dWQMzXt4qqz6mV_WCC5m-paxvQhednd",
                center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(37.09024, -95.712891),
                zoom: 5,
                enableClickableLogo: false,
                enableSearchLogo: false
            }

            dealerMap.myMap = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapDiv'), mapOptions);

            //now add some pins
            instance.addPin();           



        }

    }

    dealerMap.init();


});
```

Comment: FYI..... "bing" is a search engine. "Bing-Maps" is what your question is about

Comment: so you removed the bing tag, how helpful of you

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend only showing one infobox at a time on the map. Showing multiple infoboxes can crowd the map and make for a bad user experience. It also uses up a lot more resources. A better approach is to create a single infobox and reuse it for each pushpin as you want to display content. I wrote a blog post that shows how to do this here: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/multiple-pushpins-and-infoboxes-in-bing-maps-v7/